# How to hide the Viewcontroller at runtime?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

How do I hide the `UIViewController` at runtime?

Comment: More context needed. "The" UIViewController?

Answer (score 6):

what do you really mean?

UIViewController itself is not "visible"... 
but it is its view (a normal UIView), so just change it's view hidden propery to YES:

```
yourUIViewController.view.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: using this way you see the background of the view controller, because you set hidden only the view. So if i have viewcontroller A and i've opened with "presentViewController:animated:completion:" viewcontroller B, how can i see A without dismiss B?

Comment: sorry, but i really miss why you should present a ViewController if you don't' want to see it... if you need an instance of that controller just alloc+init it and use it without use methods to add its view to a superview of adding it in a UINavigationController stack...

Comment: because in some case i have to hide a viewController that is presented. I can't dismiss it because i can't lose the state of the element inside, to present it again in the future

Comment: then you have just to "retain" in one other class where you use it, e.g. in the previous viewController you can have a strong property pointing to it, and the next time you need it you don't alloc a new one, and just reuse the old one: if (!myVC){  self.myWC = [myVCClass alloc] init];} //then presentViewController:self.myWC ...

Answer (score 3):

If u want to hide the viewcontroller's view try

```
viewController.view.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Animations, from your Controller (I presume you have a class implementing the UIViewController protocol).

In your UIViewController Class declare a method that do something like this :

```
- (void) hide
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 //begin animation
                          delay:0.1
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn 
                     animations:^
                     {
                     // This subview is initialized at the top of the screen 
                     [mySubview setFrame:CGRectOffset([mySubview frame], 0, -mySubview.frame.size.height)];
                     // Do the same for Every other subview you want to animate off
                     } 
                     completion:nil];
}
```

That will animate your views out of the screen. It will give you a better (smooth) effect than simply making them 'hidden'.

From your superview, you just call your controller hide method and everything will smoothly go away !

Note : You can also use other animation curves...A list and description can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) under "UIViewAnimationCurve"

Answer (score 1):

code to hide current uiviewcontroller

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];